# What do I pass to schema_migration in ActiveRecord::MigrationContext#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Since the newest Rails version, `ActiveRecord::MigrationContext#new` seems to take a new argument called `schema_migration`. But I have no idea what to pass there and where to get it.

I cannot find any information on it. I googled for an hour, all examples for `MigrationContext` I found referred to older rails versions. The class MigrationContext doesn't seem to be documented at all. From the source code I couldn't figure out what to pass either.

Some context: I am trying to test some of my more dangerous migrations. I found quite a few tutorials and it seemed easy and I went along an did it. But the code that prepares the state of the test db so I can apply the migration is currently not working. Sadly all the tutorials used older Rails versions and this fails due to the wrong number of arguments:

```rb
ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new(migrations_paths)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out what I need to pass:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_migration
```

So the whole code would be:

```rb
  migrations_paths = ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_paths
  schema_migration = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_migration
  migration_context = ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new(migrations_paths, schema_migration)
```

I googled and tried for an hour and didn't figure it out, but just after posting the question, I finally stumbled upon this github issue https://github.com/pat/combustion/issues/98 which had the same problem and a solution.

Answer (score 5):

You might also just want to use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context` instead of `ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new`. No arguments needed.